# Where does devise store the user confirmation flag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't seem to find where devise flags a user as confirmed or not?

Sometimes I just want to create a user and auto-confirm the user.  I know there is a skip confirmation function but curious where this is stored in the db.

Comment: `confirmed_at` column in `users` table.

Answer (score 1):

Devise::Confirmable uses the column datatime column `confirmed_at`.

```
# Confirmable tracks the following columns:
#
# * confirmation_token   - A unique random token
# * confirmed_at         - A timestamp when the user clicked the confirmation link
# * confirmation_sent_at - A timestamp when the confirmation_token was generated (not sent)
# * unconfirmed_email    - An email address copied from the email attr. After confirmation
#                          this value is copied to the email attr then cleared
```

Since the column is nullable the implementations is as simple as:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Confirmable
      # ...
      def confirmed?
        !!confirmed_at
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which works because in Ruby everything except nil and false are true. Setting `confirmed_at` to any datetime (even in the future) will confirm the record.

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Confirmable
      # If you don't want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code
      # to be generated, call skip_confirmation!
      def skip_confirmation!
        self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
      end
    end
  end
end
```

From [the Devise source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7a7a0995739c737ba1ae4946274da6ce5cd63526/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L1).